# How do we show every linear transformation which is not bijective is the difference of bijective linear transforms?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have been reviewing some ideas about vector spaces and came upon a surprising fact. I am not quite sure how to begin the argument because the problem requires one to construct two bijective linear transformations whose difference is equal to a given linear transformation.

Let $V$ be a vector space over a filed $F$.  Suppose $\phi:V \rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation that is not a bijection.

> How do we show $\exists f,g :V \rightarrow V$ that are both bjiective linear transformations such that $\phi = f - g$.

I tried proving the fact using contradiction but have not been able to get to far so I am wondering if there is a standard constructive proof that applies directly.

Comment: Take two invertible matrices $A,B$ such that  $A-B$ is singular...

Comment: @percusse- So this shows that the difference of bijections does not need to be one. I don't think that's what user7980 is asking for, or am I misunderstanding his question?

Comment: @ChrisLeary I am sorry but in return, I did not understand your comment :) Are you commenting on the implication direction? I just gave a hint which is the compact version of  Arturo's third hint.

Comment: @user7980: Are you assuming anything about the dimension of $V$? Is it finite dimensional, or are you allowing infinite dimensional?

Comment: There are no assumptions on the dimension of V.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arturo's hints cover the case that $V$ is finite dimensional and $F$ is infinite. I add the case of $\dim V<\infty$ and a finite field $F$ with a solution that is very similar.

Let $|F|=q$ and $\dim V=n$. We fix once and for all an identification of $V$ with the field $GF(q^n)$ as vector spaces over $F$. Consider the set
$$
S=\{\phi(x)/x \mid x\in V, x\neq0\}\subseteq GF(q^n).
$$
Because $\ker\phi$ is non-trivial, $0\in S$, so the set $S$ contains at most $q^n-2$ non-zero elements. Let $\alpha\in GF(q^n)\setminus S$. Then for all non-zero $x\in V$ we have $\phi(x)\neq\alpha x$. In other words the mapping $g:V\rightarrow V$ defined by
$$
g(x)=\alpha x-\phi(x)
$$
has a trivial kernel, and is hence bijective. The mapping $f(x)=\alpha x$ is also bijective, because $\alpha\neq0$. For all $x\in V$ we have
$$
f(x)-g(x)=\alpha x-\alpha x+\phi(x)=\phi(x)
$$
as required.

Comment: I think that there should be a simpler argument. And for the general case. I tried to come up with one using different bases in the domain and in the range, but the infinite dimensional case is  trickier.

Comment: Thanks for the proof.  It looks like the way this problem was written on a previous exam they are looking for a proof that is independent of dimension.  Is there any hope of adapting something like this to the infinite dimensional case?

Answer (score 7):

**Hint 1.** Show that $a$ is an eigenvalue of $f$ if and only if $a+b$ is an eigenvalue of $f+bI$.

**Hint 2.** (Assuming $V$ is finite dimensional) Show that $f$ is bijective if and only if $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $f$.

**Hint 3.** (Assuming the field is infinite) Show that if $f$ is not bijective, then there is a nonzero scalar $b$ such that $f+bI$ is bijective.

Comment: Thanks for the hints they are very clear and informative.  Is there a way we can modify hint 2 to account for the infinite dimensional case?

Comment: @user7980: The condition that $0$ is not an eigenvalue is necessary, but not sufficient (since in the infinite-dimensional case, you can have a one-to-one linear transformation that is not onto; e.g., the right-shift operator on the direct product (or sum) of countably many copies of the field. I've been thinking about it on and off, but can't yet think of a way of either ensuring it works, or coming up with a counterexample.